# Django-filters field forms doesn't show in HTML

Tags: django, django-filter

I try to use django-filters in my Django app. I am using it with pagination. Page renders properly (it just works), but without filter fields that I created. Only submit button shows. I will be really thankful for any help i don't know what I am doing wrong.

I want to use ModelChoiceFilter to filter objects from Image model, by their foreign key Publisher

filters.py

```
# filters.py

import django_filters
from django import forms
from .models import Image, Publisher, Author


class ImageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['title', 'created']
        
class ImageForeignFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    wydawca = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Publisher.objects.all(),
        empty_label="Wszyscy wydawcy",
        label="Wydawca",
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['created', 'wydawca']
```

models.py

```
# models.py

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='',blank=True, verbose_name="Nazwa wydawcy", help_text="Nazwa wydawcy")
    urlglowna = models.URLField(max_length=2000, default='', blank=True, verbose_name="Strona główna", help_text="Adres strony")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name,self.urlglowna)


class Image(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=2000, verbose_name="Link do znaleziska", help_text="Podaj bezpośredni link")
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
# views.py

def image_list(request):
    images = ImageForeignFilter(
                      request.GET, queryset=Image.objects.filter(status=Image.Status.PUBLISHED).order_by('created')
                  ).qs
    paginator = Paginator(images, 15)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        page_number = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page_number = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        page_number = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'images/image/list.html', {'section': 'images','images': images, 'page_number': page_number})
```

template

```
# template

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}


{% block title %}Title{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div id="image-list">

  <form method="get">
    {{ images.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
  {% for user in images.qs %}
  {{ user.wydawca }}
  {% endfor %}

                
                
{% include "images/image/list_images.html" %}
{% include "pagination.html" with page=images %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you need .qs at the end of your filter in your views.py?

Comment: I am not sure, I used it because it was in one answer here to make pagination work. Do you recommend me to delete it?

Comment: Worth a try - you are passing ImageForeignFilter().qs in your context then using it again in your template which would be ImageForeignFilter().qs.qs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ok, it works for me:

#template
        <form method="get">
            {{ images_filter.form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Filtruj"/>
        </form>
    
#filters
    class ImageForeignFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        publisher = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
            queryset=Publisher.objects.all(),
            empty_label="Wszyscy wydawcy",
            label="Wydawca",
            widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            )      
        class Meta:
            model = Image
            fields = ['publisher']

#view
def image_list(request):
    qs = Image.objects.filter(status=Image.Status.PUBLISHED).order_by('created')
    images_filter = ImageForeignFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)
    paginator = Paginator(images_filter.qs, 15)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        images = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        images = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        images = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'images/image/list.html', {'section': 'images','images': images, 'images_filter': images_filter})
```